# $http & JSESSIONID with Glassfish

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, glassfish

I have a backend using Java which produces JSON for the services, which client will need to login/be authenticated using cookies based (JSESSIONID in Java).
I manage to receive JSESSIONID from server, however concecutive $http.get from client does not include previous generated JSESSIONID  which I supposed to be automated handle by $http ?

The case:

## Step 1

When I tested my login page using $http.post using valid user id and password, I can get an expected result from my server, I can get a generated JSESSIONID from the server, i.e.:
set-cookie:JSESSIONID=0a624257d0f704840bf6d8c8cc31; Path=/tmh-web; HttpOnly
(pls refer to screenshot in Response Header)

[after call Login & been auhthenticated screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5JRf.png)

## Step 2

After been authenticated, when tried to call another URL service which requires authentication, I got an error: "403 Forbidden"
And I suspected this is because $http does not send the JSessionID it has received on Step 1.
(pls refer to screenshot in Request Header, there is no JSessionID has been sent back to server)

[call next service which requires authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aME4J.png)

Has anyone experienced this problem with Java as the backend server ?

Answer (score 0):

Use / for path attribute of the cookie.